# Emacs Org-Mode: How to set date and time on the first Wednesday of month

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to add a date and time for an event in org-mode that will repeat on the first Wednesday of each month.

I know I can use the diary-sexp format to identify the first Wednesday of each month, like so:

```
* My Special Event
  <%%(diary-float t 3 1)>
```

This works, but I also need to specify the *time* when that event occurs (ideally both the start and end times). I've tried both of the following:

```
<%%(diary-float t 3 1) 19:30>
<%%(diary-float t 3 1) 19:30-20:30>
```

...but neither works.

Is this even possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/DiaryMode#toc5  gives custom formats for your calendar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following to get the desired effect

```
* My Special Event 19:30-20:30
  <%%(diary-float t 3 1)>
```

It will output in your agenda as (Agenda trimmed):

```
            18:00...... ----------------
filename:   19:30-20:30 My Special Event
            20:00...... ----------------
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html

check "Diary-style expression entries"